# Call command history when script is Run with pdb in PyCharm

Tags: console, pycharm, pdb

When I use `Run` in `PyCharm 3.4` (Windows 8.1) for this script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
x = 'lolo'
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
print(x)
```

I navigate to `Run Tool Window` where I can play with `pdb`:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/check/old/stack.py
> d:\check\old\stack.py(4)<module>()
-> print(x)
(Pdb) x
'lolo'
(Pdb)
```

But I cannot figure out how to call last command / navigate through history of commands.
<kbd>↑</kbd>, or with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> gives nothing :(
In build in PyCharm **Terminal** or in **Windows Command Prompt** / **Git Bash** it works as expected.
Maybe there is some configuration of `Run` what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

They state that this has already been implemented as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (configurable via Settings > Keymaps > Other > Browse History (see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7622) or as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1199).

However, both didn't work for me either.